# numpy sub-gridding an cartesian product

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, numpy

So I have a cartesian product c of two (or more) vectors, a and b. I want to get a cartesian product of a[::i] and b[::j] from c.

This means the new cartesian product will skip every ith a-item, and every jth b-item.

For instance

```
veclens = (3,6)

# <code that generates cross product c here> (I have that). 
# result:
c = array([
[0,0],
[0,1],
[0,2],
[0,3],
[0,4],
[0,5],
[1,0],
[1,1],
[1,2],
[1,3],
[1,4],
[1,5],
[2,0],
[2,1],
[2,2],
[2,3],
[2,4],
[2,5]])

print c.shape 
(18, 2)

samples = (2,2) # so we want every 2nd item a, and every 2nd in b

# this is the function I would like:
d = get_subarray(c, samples, veclens)

# and now d is something like
array([
[0,0],
[0,2],
[0,4],
[2,0],
[2,2],
[2,4]])
```

Any idea how to write get_subarray without calculating the array c from scratch (which is expensive, because it is actually a function evaluated on the crossproduct of a and b). Surely there is some indexing trick?

I am looking for something like the following, but more general, more elegant and faster.

```
def get_subarray(c, samples, veclens):
    indexes = []
    for i in range(0, veclens[0], samples[0]):
        for j in range(0, veclens[1], samples[1]):
            indexes.append(i * veclens[1] + j)
    return c[indexes]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general solution using ix_:

```
def get_subarray(c, samples, veclens):
    n = len(veclens)
    d = c.reshape(veclens+[n])
    i = numpy.ix_(*[range(0, l, s) for l,s in zip(veclens,samples)]
    return d[i].reshape((-1,n)
```